# SQL Server - Retrieve two rows in a unique row using alias

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `LOGPROCESS` that stores start/end of each process and I would like to do a select and return only one row using something like 'as DateStart' 'as DateEnd'.

This is how the logs are saved for each process ( ThreadName could be different ):

```
|ThreadName                         |LEVEL  |Who        | TYPE              | QUERY_STRING                          | DATE
|DevTest                            |INFO   |Tests.Run  | [RECURRING_START] | clientId=300&campId=3130              | 2014-06-27 15:42:57.803
|62013c67-886e-455b-b8aa-ef9139fcc1d4|INFO  |Tests.Send | [RECURRING_END]   | clientId=300&campId=3130&totalSends=0 | 2014-06-27 15:43:58.701
```

The only values that represents that START/END are from the same process is part of query string called `CampId`.

I'm trying to perform a select like this ( name of end thread is the only that interest ):

```
select ThreadName,
 (SELECT Date from logprocess  where <what goes here>) as DateStart    
 (SELECT Date fromlogprocess  where <what goes here>) as DateEnd
from logprocess where
```

But I didn't find out what should put between <> .

My desired output is something like (the ThreadName from EndProcess, Date from Start process and Date from EndProcess):

```
|ThreadName                           | STARTDATE               | ENDDATE   
|62013c67-886e-455b-b8aa-ef9139fcc1d4 | 2014-06-27 15:42:57.803 | 2014-06-27 15:43:58.701
```

Any help?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What would be the desired result for the data sample that you posted?

Comment: @Lamak the desired result is something like ThreadName ( from End ), DateStart and DateEnd. And in a unique row for Start / End.

Comment: There are no dates in your table.  Where are they coming from?  As Lamak said, what specific date are you wanting based on your example?

Comment: If `CampID` is the identifier in the query string I would really recommend parsing this in the application layer and storing it as it's own column. You don't want to have to rely on splitting up the query string in SQL every time you need to know what it is in it. If you will have variable Key/value pairs at the very least consider parsing the query string to XML so that SQL Server's XML extensions can be used to access each pair

Comment: @Dave.Gugg Date is the last Column. It was missing from my example. Look now, please.

Comment: @GarethD I only have this columns and this can not be changed so i need to parse the value in my query.

Comment: @DavidL. You posted sample date, can't you write the desired output **with that same data** please?, I understand the columns you want but I don't understand the results you want

Comment: @Lamak check the edit now, i put the example from output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your challenge is extracting `CampID` from your query string to identify your rows. You can do this using CHARINDEX and SUBSTRING as follows (I have separated out the logic into APPLY to hopefully make it more clear what is being done):

```
SELECT  CampID = SUBSTRING(QUERY_STRING, StartIndex, EndIndex - StartIndex),
        t.*
FROM    T
-- FIND POSITION OF '&CampID=' IN QUERY_STRING
CROSS APPLY (SELECT StartIndex = CHARINDEX('&campID=', '&' + QUERY_STRING) + 7) si
-- FIND POSITION OF '&' AFTER '$CampID=' IN QUERY_STRING
CROSS APPLY (SELECT EndIndex = CHARINDEX('&', QUERY_STRING + '&', StartIndex + 1)) ei;
```

Once you have your CampID, it is then fairly simple to get your data out using conditional aggregates:

```
SELECT  CampID = SUBSTRING(QUERY_STRING, StartIndex, EndIndex - StartIndex),
        ThreadName = MAX(CASE WHEN [TYPE] = '[RECURRING_END]' THEN ThreadName END),
        StartDate = MAX(CASE WHEN [TYPE] = '[RECURRING_START]' THEN [DATE] END),
        EndDate = MAX(CASE WHEN [TYPE] = '[RECURRING_END]' THEN [DATE] END)
FROM    T t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT StartIndex = CHARINDEX('&campID=', '&' + QUERY_STRING) + 7) si
CROSS APPLY (SELECT EndIndex = CHARINDEX('&', QUERY_STRING + '&', StartIndex + 1)) ei
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(QUERY_STRING, StartIndex, EndIndex - StartIndex);
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5f885/1)**

Comment: This query works with multiple sets of processes as well. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b08cb/1

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's not pretty:

```
SELECT b.ThreadName
      ,a.[date] as StartDate
      ,b.[date] as EndDate
FROM logprocess a 
LEFT JOIN logprocess b
  ON SUBSTRING(a.query_string
              ,PATINDEX('%campId=%', a.query_string)+7
              ,LEN(a.query_string)-(PATINDEX('%campId=%', a.query_string)+6))
   = SUBSTRING(b.query_string
              ,PATINDEX('%campId=%', a.query_string)+7
              ,LEN(a.query_string)-(PATINDEX('%campId=%', a.query_string)+6))
WHERE a.type = '[RECURRING_START]'
  AND b.type = '[RECURRING_END]'
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/36bc3/17)

This should work as long as the the `campId` is always the last variable in the `[RECURRING_START]` row, and then appears in the same position in the `[RECURRING_END]` row. I would imagine it's incredibly slow.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a join in order to have different Where clauses for the same field, and use the common field to link them.

```
select a.<commonField>, a.Date as DateStart, b.Date as DateEnd
from logprocess a
inner join logprocess b on a.<commonField>= b.<commonField>
where a.Type = "RECURRING_START"
and b.Type = "RECURRING_END"
```

Comment: There is no common field

Comment: I don't have a common field. I just have part of string from a fiend that are common between registers.

Comment: Your threadName is not common ? So how do you choose which threadName to display ?

Comment: No. It can be variable this is why i'm suffering.

Comment: I only need the threadName from EndProcess...don't matter the name from start process

Comment: how do you know which [RECURRING_START] to pair with each [RECURRING_END]?